# Group streetnames depends on hops/steps in the numeration

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

i have a df that has 4 values. they are the name of street and the numeration(start,end) and if it is odd or even. what i need is to group the numerations of a specific streetname between the min column and the end column, but if there is a gap greater than 100(that means the numbers arent use in that street) it has to group the next range in a separate series with the same street. this df is like this because each row represents an entire block in my city, but i want to leave only the ranges of numbers that street has, and to know the extend of the street.

What  i managed to do so far is a column to count the changes of step called
"group_ids", and then group the dataframe depends of "street", "description", "end", and "group_ids". but i cant make the code to work properly .

| street | descripcion | start | end | group_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2201 | 2299 | 0 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2301 | 2399 | 0 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2401 | 2499 | 0 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2501 | 2599 | 1 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2801 | 2899 | 1 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2901 | 2949 | 1 |

in this table it should change the value in "group_ids" when the value "end" is 2899 but it changes before in 2499

this the code that i have so far and added the line where i do the groupby

```html
df = df.sort_values(["street","descripcion","start","end"],ascending=[True,True,True,True])
df["group_ids"] = (df.end+100 < df.end.shift(periods=-1)).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(["street","descripcion","group_ids"],as_index=False).agg({"start":"min","end":"max"})
```

this the link of the excel https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1leNMvDVwU9BHyOClxzDq07RWlS63zwbKiuoIPI5Tnv8/edit?usp=sharing

this is the output that i get

| street | descripcion | group_ids | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 0 | 801 | 2499 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 1 | 2501 | 4399 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2 | 4401 | 4799 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 2 | 800 | 2498 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 3 | 2500 | 4398 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 4 | 4400 | 4798 |

but it should be

| street | descripcion | group_ids | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 0 | 801 | 2599 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 1 | 2801 | 4499 |
| 1 DE MAYO | odd | 2 | 4601 | 4799 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 2 | 800 | 2598 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 3 | 2800 | 4498 |
| 1 DE MAYO | even | 4 | 4600 | 4798 |

so this the solution that i found, maybe its not the most efficient, but here it is:

```html
df["diff"]= df["start"] - df["end"].shift()

df["step"]=( df["diff"] != 2).cumsum()

df=df.groupby(["street","descripcion","step"],as_index=False).agg({"start":"min","end":"max"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the grouping boundaries are not just based on `end`.

```
df = df.sort_values(["street","descripcion","start","end"],ascending=[True,True,True,True])
df
```

```
       street descripcion  start   end
43  1 DE MAYO        even    800   898
44  1 DE MAYO        even    900   998
45  1 DE MAYO        even   1000  1098
46  1 DE MAYO        even   1100  1198
47  1 DE MAYO        even   1200  1298
..        ...         ...    ...   ...
38  1 DE MAYO         odd   4301  4399
39  1 DE MAYO         odd   4401  4499
40  1 DE MAYO         odd   4601  4649
41  1 DE MAYO         odd   4651  4699
42  1 DE MAYO         odd   4701  4799
```

The boundaries are subject to three conditions.

```
c1 = df['end'].diff() > 100
c2 = df['street'] == df['street'].shift(-1)
c3 = df['descripcion'] == df['descripcion'].shift(-1)
```

chain these conditions and `cumsum()`:

```
df['group_ids'] = (c1*c2*c3).cumsum()
```

Assign to another dataframe for better observation:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["street","descripcion","group_ids"],as_index=False).agg({"start":"min","end":"max"})
df2
```

[image]
According to your sorting from `df` at the beginning, the first `group_ids`=0 corresponds to
`1 DE MAYO`,`even`

---

If we wanna get the same result from your post, the sorting part should become:

```
df = df.sort_values(["street","descripcion","start","end"],ascending=[True,False,True,True])
```

Sort the result `df2` as well.

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(["street","descripcion","start","end"],ascending=[True,False,True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i think its better than the solution i found. im going to post the solution that i found in the question.